# Form type markup states

Tags: forms

Is it possible to create a form element of type markup and add a state to it, to make it visible on a condition? I can't seem to make it work and get the error:

Warning: Undefined array key "#type" in Drupal\Core\Form\FormHelper::processStates() (line 211 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormHelper.php)

I need to just add some text in the form and make it visible on a condition.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hello @jacksparrow, could you add your code to the question please.  My current suspicion is that the form element doesn't include '#type' => 'markup'.  Typically the #type isn't needed for the 'markup' element but adding the States API into the mix may be making that required.

Comment: Thanks @Gold, yes actually the type markup was not added, but it is no longer valid, so #type item did the work! Just got it working, Thanks for your your help.

Answer (score 1):

Adding form type item did the trick:

```
$form['my_incomes'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('My other incomes'),
      '#states' => [
        'visible' => [
          [':input[name="marital_status"]' => [['value' => 'single'],['value'=>'couple']]],
        ]
      ]
    ];
```